# Chatkit: creating new user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chatkit

I am following tutorial on here: https://docs.pusher.com/chatkit/quick_start/javascript

There is an example how to create user:

```
const chatkit = new Chatkit.default({
  instanceLocator: "YOUR INSTANCE LOCATOR",
  key: "YOUR SECRET KEY"
})

chatkit.createUser({
  id: "bookercodes",
  name: "Alex Booker"
})
```

However, when I am trying to run this code with my instanceLocator and key it gives me an error in the console:

```
SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action
```

Nore that I everything else Chatkit related works fine. I am just not able to create the new user.

Comment: As it says in the [section you copied from](https://pusher.com/docs/chatkit/quick_start/javascript#create-a-user), you should not copy paste this code. You must at least replace values of `instanceLocator` and `key`.

Answer (score 1):

## Setting `instanceLocator` and `key`

You must replace the values of `instanceLocator` and `key` passed to

```js
new Chatkit.default({
    instanceLocator: "?",
    key: "?"
})
```

To find the correct values, go to https://dash.pusher.com/chatkit and select the chatkit app you want to use.

On the next page, click the *Credentisals* tab as shown below:

[image: Credentials tab in chatkit dashboard]

Where you see `<instanceLocator>` in the screenshot you will find the string to use for `instanceLocator`, and where you see `<key>` you will find the string to use for `key`.

## Creating user

If you want to create the user `{ id: "bookercodes", name: "Alex Booker" }` as soon as you start the server, just to test that it works, then your code should work after you do as described above.

Answer (score 0):

That's an IE11 error. Which browser are you using? Try Chrome.